# Regex for preg_preplace urls with proper URLs only

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all, preg-replace-callback

I have basic knowledge in regex and I have managed to do a url detect and replace with html '' tag link.  Currently I have a working code; currently I detect links like following

```
    http://google.com
    https://google.com
    www.google.com
    https://www.google.com
    google.com
```

What I am trying to achieve is avoid 'google.com' from detecting as a URL because if it detect 'google.com' as a URL, it will also detect a text/name like 'rameez.rami'.

```
<?php
$string = ' rameez.rami https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=migrate+from+mysql+to+oracle plz use http:// links instead of https:// links and http:hi all plse chec http://teams.lear.com/sites/Design_Guidelines/Design%20Guidelines/B_GLOBAL_ENGINEERING_DESIGN_GUIDELINES/Guideline%20Creation%20Instructions.pptx http://www.google.com https://www.google.com https://www.google.com http://google.com https://google.com google.com';

        $urlRegex = '@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';
        $result = preg_replace($urlRegex, '<a href="$0">$4</a>', $string);
        print_r($result);
        die;
?>
```

Current output is:

```
<a href="rameez.rami">rameez.rami</a> <a href="https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=migrate+from+mysql+to+oracle">www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=migrate+from+mysql+to+oracle</a> plz use http:// links instead of https:// links and http:hi all plse chec <a href="http://teams.lear.com/sites/Design_Guidelines/Design%20Guidelines/B_GLOBAL_ENGINEERING_DESIGN_GUIDELINES/Guideline%20Creation%20Instructions.pptx">teams.lear.com/sites/Design_Guidelines/Design%20Guidelines/B_GLOBAL_ENGINEERING_DESIGN_GUIDELINES/Guideline%20Creation%20Instructions.pptx</a>  <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">www.google.com</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">www.google.com</a> <a href="http://google.com">google.com</a> <a href="https://google.com">google.com</a> <a href="google.com">google.com</a>
```

My expected out:

```
rameez.rami <a href="https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=migrate+from+mysql+to+oracle">www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=migrate+from+mysql+to+oracle</a> plz use http:// links instead of https:// links and http:hi all plse chec <a href="http://teams.lear.com/sites/Design_Guidelines/Design%20Guidelines/B_GLOBAL_ENGINEERING_DESIGN_GUIDELINES/Guideline%20Creation%20Instructions.pptx">teams.lear.com/sites/Design_Guidelines/Design%20Guidelines/B_GLOBAL_ENGINEERING_DESIGN_GUIDELINES/Guideline%20Creation%20Instructions.pptx</a> <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">www.google.com</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">www.google.com</a> <a href="http://google.com">google.com</a> <a href="https://google.com">google.com</a> google.com
```

Comment: You have to define TLDs then.

Comment: To add to what Revo has said, please try creating a regex involving the detection of specific top-level domains. Since `rami` is not a TLD that will not be detected. Give that a try, and if you run into problems please ask a new question.

Comment: @halfer iam not really good with regex, if you could help me that would be really helpful, meanwhile i'll dig more into TLD .

Comment: @revo hi there are lots of possible list of TLD so i cant validate TLD with that list. is there any way i can can stop detecting 'rameez.rami' or 'google.com'

Answer (score 0):

Please post if you guys found a better answer.

For temporary purpose I have done it using `preg_replace_callback` function.

```
$urlRegex = '@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';
        $content = ' rameez.rami https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=migrate+from+mysql+to+oracle plz use http:// links instead of https:// links and http:hi all plse chec http://teams.lear.com/sites/Design_Guidelines/Design%20Guidelines/B_GLOBAL_ENGINEERING_DESIGN_GUIDELINES/Guideline%20Creation%20Instructions.pptx also check http://teams.lear.com/sites/Design_Guidelines/Design%20Guidelines/B_GLOBAL_ENGINEERING_DESIGN_GUIDELINES/Guideline%20Creation%20Instructions.pptx http://www.google.com https://www.google.com https://www.google.com http://google.com https://google.com google.com';

        $content = preg_replace_callback(
            $urlRegex,
            function ($matches) use($linkClass){
                $link = $matches[0];
                if (!filter_var($link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
                    return '<a class="'.$linkClass.'" href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" title="'.$link.'">'.$matches[4].'</a>';
                }else{
                    return $link;
                }
            },
            $content
        );
        print_r($content);die;
```

Comment: Please do not shout or use txtspk here. Would you use the edit link to improve this?

Comment: what do you mean? where did i shout anyone? may be its my bad english, plz edit answer

Comment: No: the use of all-caps is [widely thought to mean shouting](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=all+caps+shouting&ia=answer), and has done on the internet for the last ~25 years or so. Your caps-lock clearly works, so would you fix it? Editors have enough work to do without having to rewrite posts as well.